# Are there please any statistics on users and their time zones?

Tags: support, users, site-statistics

I posted a new question on Friday at around 10 am British Summer Time. I wonder when the responses will start coming in.

Are there please  any statistics on users and their time zones?

(It's not that vital that I will check each user's information  individually).

Comment: I don't think there's anything directly on the site that provides that information in the aggregate, but one could do something similar in SEDE: analyze post activity over time of day since your real question is *when are people active*.  Location data (for users who disclosed it) is also available through SEDE, but then you'd have to map that to timezones and that might be time-consuming.  (No geo-coordinates, only text strings that could be anything.)  I can't write that first query right at the moment, so I'm leaving a comment -- maybe somebody else can.

Comment: There's also this http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1635/759

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/334820/posting-users-and-posts-by-hour-of-day-friday-and-saturday-gmt?DaysOfHistory=999999#graph) is a SEDE query that counts the number of distinct users who have posted, and the number of posts posted, during each hour of the day on Friday and Saturday GMT.

On the X axis:

- 0 = 00:00 GMT Friday, or 7pm EST / 8pm EDT Thursday
- 12 = 12:00 GMT Friday, or 7am EST / 8am EST Friday
- 24 = 00:00 GMT Saturday, or 7pm EST / 8pm EDT Friday
- 36 = 12:00 GMT Saturday, or 7am EST / 8am EST Saturday
- 48 = 00:00 GMT Sunday, or 7pm EST / 8pm EDT Saturday

The graph shows that 10am BST (09:00 GMT / 5am EDT) is toward the end of a ~4-hour period of US-Eastern night that typically sees low posting activity, with activity ramping up for the next ~4 hours after that and staying high for the next ~7 hours.

It also shows that posting activity is typically very low over Shabbat. For a more seasonal look at how long the site's Shabbat lasts, see the same graph, for the past [90 days](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/334820/posting-users-and-posts-by-hour-of-day-friday-and-saturday-gmt?DaysOfHistory=90#graph).

[Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/334859/posting-users-and-posts-by-hour-of-day-and-day-of-week-gmt?DaysOfHistory=999999#graph)'s another, more general query that shows every hour of the week. In this graph, 0 and 168 on the x-axis are 00:00 GMT Sunday, 24 is 00:00 GMT Monday, and so on.

Comment: The week-long graph really shows that the eastern US dominates.